# When creating a contract getting the error "Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount"

Tags: contract-deployment

I wrote the following contract :

```
contract EndowmentRetriever {

    address creator;
    uint contract_creation_value;

    function EndowmentRetriever() public payable {
        creator = msg.sender;
        contract_creation_value = msg.value;
    }

    function getContractCreationValue() constant returns (uint) {                               
        return contract_creation_value;                         
    }

    function sendOneEtherHome() public {                        
        creator.send(1000000000000000000);
    }

    function kill() { 
        if (msg.sender == creator) {
            suicide(creator); 
        }
    }   
}
```

When I am creating a new contract using the following transaction

```
var EdRet = edRetContract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: edRetCompiled.EdRetriever.code, gas: 1000000, value: 3000000000000000000}, function(e, contract){ 
    if(!e) { 
        if(!contract.address) { 
            console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined..."); } 
        else { 
            console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address); 
            console.log(contract); } 
        } 
    else { 
        console.log(e); } 
    })
```

I am getting the following error message :

```
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
```

If I remove the value parameter in the transaction(i.e. the initial endowment to the contract),  then the contract got mined. What could be the possible reason.

Answer (score 1):

try to send more gas, i propose you to use  `gas:gasEstimate+30000`

```
 var EdRet = edRetContract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: edRetCompiled.EdRetriever.code,
      gas:gasEstimate+30000, value: 3000000000000000000}, function(e, contract){ 
        ...
```

Comment: already tried this, it is not working, getting the same error.

Comment: are you using parity?

Comment: I have been testing your contract and there are some weird things happening, and it's to do with the `payable` modifier. 1. You cannot send ethers when you are creating the contract, even if you specify the `payable` modifier. 2. When you have a payable function that modifies the `contract_creation_value` variable, there will be an exception retrieving the `contract_creation_value` value. I'll try to investigate further over the next few days.

Comment: @ Badr Bellaj, I am using geth

Comment: @ BokkaPooBah : regarding your point 1) if I cannot send ether when creating the contract, then how can I make initial endowment.